# No legend in QGis Web Client

Tags: qgis

I have a QGIS Web Client working, but it lacks a legend and metadata panel as is shown [here](http://www.qgis.org/about-qgis/features.html)

What do I need to have the referred legend panel?

Answer (score 1):

That panel was removed.

Now if you want the "legend" it looks like it may be limited to a single layer at a time!
You can [submit a feature request](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/qgis-web-client/issues?set_filter=1&tracker_id=2) if you like.

I loved the old legend as it was important for users to understand what some features are when they aren't self explanatory.

Now you have to click on a layer (the little "i") to get info:
[image: qgis web client - new legend and metadata window]

The bottom panel is now a layer order, visibility and transparency tool:
[image: qgis web client - layer order]